# PHP, SimpleXML, Parsing the document

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xpath, simplexml

I am a beginner to manipulating, or even reading, XML documents with php.

If I have the given XML document below, how would I parse and display specific points of this XML document with PHP (using SimpleXML and/or xPath)...?

Your help and basic examples would be very much appreciated! I will provide positive feedback!

```
    <week id="1">
        <matchup id="1" date="09/08/11" time="8:30 P.M.">
            <away city="New Orleans">Saints</away>
            <home city="Green Bay">Packers</home>
            <final>
                <away score="">
                <home score="">
            </final>
        </matchup>
        <matchup id="2" date="09/11/11" time="1:00 P.M.">
            <away city="Atlanta">Falcons</away>
            <home city="Chicago">Bears</home>
            <final>
                <away score="">
                <home score="">
            </final>
        </matchup>
     </week>
    <week id="2">
        <matchup id="1" date="09/22/11" time="1:00 P.M.">
            <away city="Chicago">Bears</away>
            <home city="Tampa Bay">Buccaneers</home>
            <final>
                <away score="">
                <home score="">
            </final>
        </matchup>
        <matchup id="2" date="09/22/11" time="1:00 P.M.">
            <away city="Carolina">Panthers</away>
            <home city="St. Louis">Rams</home>
            <final>
                <away score="">
                <home score="">
            </final>
        </matchup>
     </week>
```

Thanks!

Comment: That depends greatly on what you want to display. From your question it sounds like you know what to do (use simpleXML and/or Xpath) have you tried anything yet based on the simpleXML docs and an xpath turorial/documentaion?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good tutorial that gets never fails anyone

[Using XML in PHP](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/651)

might aswell read the rest here

[Php for Beginnners](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627-PHP-101-PHP-For-the-Absolute-Beginner)

To quote from the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pet>
    <name>Polly Parrot</name>
    <age>3</age>
    <species>parrot</species>
    <parents>
        <mother>Pia Parrot</mother>
        <father>Peter Parrot</father>
    </parents>
</pet>
```

PHP

```
<?php

// set name of XML file
$file = "pet.xml";

// load file
$xml = simplexml_load_file($file) or die ("Unable to load XML file!");

// access XML data
echo "Name: " . $xml->name . "\n";
echo "Age: " . $xml->age . "\n";
echo "Species: " . $xml->species . "\n";
echo "Parents: " . $xml->parents->mother . " and " .  $xml->parents->father . "\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);` or `$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);` you can output the `$xml` variable with `print_r($xml);` to inspect the structure of the parsed input. This can be very helpful with understanding how to manipulate the output.